# Checkbox filter among other filters

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to apply a checkbox filter in a ms-access query with SQL. It is a multiple filter query based on fields of a form, the filters based on texts fields are fine as you can see in the code below, but I can't figure out how to make a checkbox filter work, I tried lots of examples online but none of them worked. One of the things I tried was: AND (Len([Formulários]![frmFC]![cbxPago] & '') = 0 OR pago Like '*' & '> 0' & '*')

Better code for the one I'm currently using is welcome ;)

```
PARAMETERS [Formulários]![frmFC]![txtCriadoEm] Text ( 255 );

SELECT tabFcGas.criadoEm, tabFcGas.Cliente, tabFcGas.valor, 
       tabFcGas.vencimento, tabFcGas.parcela, tabFcGas.totalParcelas, 
       tabFcGas.pago, tabFcGas.classificacao, tabFcGas.obs, tabFcGas.nf
FROM tabFcGas
WHERE (Len([Formulários]![frmFC]![txtCriadoEm] & '') = 0 
       OR criadoEm Like '*' & [Formulários]![frmFC]![txtCriadoEm] & '*') 
  AND (Len([Formulários]![frmFC]![cmbCliente] & '') = 0 
       OR Cliente Like '*' & [Formulários]![frmFC]![cmbCliente] & '*') 
  AND (vencimento BETWEEN NZ([Formulários]![frmFC]![txtDataIni],#01/01/2001#) 
       AND NZ([Formulários]![frmFC]![txtDataFin],#01/01/2050#)) 
  AND (Len([Formulários]![frmFC]![cmbInvestimento] & '') = 0 
       OR classificacao Like '*' & [Formulários]![frmFC]![cmbInvestimento] & '*') 
  AND (Len([Formulários]![frmFC]![txtVencimento] & '') = 0 
       OR Vencimento Like '*' & [Formulários]![frmFC]![txtVencimento] & '*')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes are either 1 (checked) or 0 (unchecked).  You could also use True for checked and False for unchecked.

You should probably create a separate test query just to make sure your SQL is correct, and in this query just test the checkbox piece.  If it works, then your syntax is fine and you can add it to your longer, more complex query.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I solved the problem working by parts, the functional code is:WHERE (iif(forms!frmFC!cmbPago = "Pago",Pago BETWEEN #01/01/2001# AND #01/01/2050#,iif(forms!frmFC!cmbPago = "Aberto",Pago IS NULL,Pago IS NULL OR "")))

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please click the checkmark to the left so I get points.  Thanks!